# How to keep clipped area constant while resizing a container dynamically in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a following code which has an image that is cropped to 150px by default. What I want is to make this cropped area remain constant while resizing the container using the resize handle.

I want the resize happen like so: (See how the cropped area is constant i.e. it doesn't move. It's as if I'm resizing an image of cropped width & height)

[image]

But in my code, it works like this:

[image]

See how the cropped area also gets cropped when resizing. I want to keep the cropped area constant(not move) while resizing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';


void main() {
  debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Test(),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  double _cropWidth = 150;
  double _width = 300;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            child: ClipRect(
              clipper: Cropper(
                height: 200,
                width: _cropWidth,
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
              ),
              child: Image.network(
                "https://picresize.com/images/t1rsz_pexels-photo-1108099.jpg",
                height: 200,
                width: _width,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            child: Container(
              height: 200,
              width: _cropWidth,
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Positioned(
                    top: 80,
                    left: _cropWidth - 20,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onPanUpdate: (d) {
                        _cropWidth = _cropWidth + d.delta.dx;
                        _width = _width + d.delta.dx;
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                      child:
                          Container(height: 20, width: 20, color: Colors.blue),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Cropper extends CustomClipper<Rect> {
  final double left;
  final double top;
  final double width;
  final double height;

  const Cropper({
    this.left = 0.0,
    this.top = 0.0,
    this.width = 0.0,
    this.height = 0.0,
  });

  @override
  Rect getClip(Size a) {
    return Rect.fromLTWH(left, top, width, height);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Rect> old) => true;
}
```

Comment: Can you use please replace the placeholder image in your question with an actual stock image like this one : https://images.pexels.com/photos/1108099/pexels-photo-1108099.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500 It is difficult to understand what you are expecting.

Comment: @bluenile Give me 2 mins

Comment: @bluenile Please check the edit

Comment: @bluenile See how the dog disappears in 2nd GIF. I don't want that. I want the functionality shown in 1st GIF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem in **cropWidth**. The problem is in the original image width.

[image]

You may notice the area `cropWidth` and `width` should be related in some **ratio**. You should calculate *crop width* from *width* (or reverse).

In your problem, the ratio seems to be a fixed number:

```
double _ratio = 0.5;
double _cropWidth = 150;
double _width = 300;

...
   onPanUpdate: (d) {
     _cropWidth = _cropWidth + d.delta.dx;
     _width = _cropWidth / _ratio;
     setState(() {});
   }
   ...
```

If you want, you can change the crop ratio by modifying it

```
Positioned(
  top: 120,
  left: _cropWidth - 20,
  child: GestureDetector(
    onPanUpdate: (d) {
      _cropWidth = _cropWidth + d.delta.dx;
      _ratio = _cropWidth / _width;
      setState(() {});
    },
    child:
      Container(height: 20, width: 20, color: Colors.green),
  ),
),
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was struggling with it for days. @yellowgray

Answer (score 1):

**Is this what you want?**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';


void main() {
  debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Test(),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  double _cropWidth = 300;
  double _width = 300;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            child: ClipRect(
              clipper: Cropper(
                height: 200,
                width: _cropWidth,
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
              ),
              child: Image.network(
                "https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/dog-puppy-on-garden-royalty-free-image-1586966191.jpg",
                height: 200,
                width: _width,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            child: Container(
              height: 200,
              width: _cropWidth,
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Positioned(
                    top: 80,
                    left: _cropWidth - 20,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onPanUpdate: (d) {
                        _cropWidth = _cropWidth + d.delta.dx;
                        _width = _width + d.delta.dx;
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                      child:
                      Container(height: 20, width: 20, color: Colors.blue),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Cropper extends CustomClipper<Rect> {
  final double left;
  final double top;
  final double width;
  final double height;

  const Cropper({
    this.left = 0.0,
    this.top = 0.0,
    this.width = 0.0,
    this.height = 0.0,
  });

  @override
  Rect getClip(Size a) {
    return Rect.fromLTWH(left, top, width, height);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Rect> old) => true;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i am also try this to do thing, may be its helpful for you

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';


void main() {
  debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Test(),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}
class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  double _cropWidth = 350;
  double _width = 350;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          ClipRect(
            clipper: Cropper(
              height: 200,
              width: _cropWidth,
            ),
            child: Image.network(
              "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1108099/pexels-photo-1108099.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
              height: 200,
              width: _width,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 200,
            width: _cropWidth,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                  top: 80,
                  left: _cropWidth - 20,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onPanUpdate: (d) {
                      _cropWidth = _cropWidth + d.delta.dx;
                      _width = _width + d.delta.dx;
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                    child:
                    Container(height: 20, width: 20, color: Colors.blue),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Cropper extends CustomClipper<Rect> {
  final double left;
  final double top;
  final double width;
  final double height;

  const Cropper({
    this.left = 0.0,
    this.top = 0.0,
    this.width = 0.0,
    this.height = 0.0,
  });

  @override
  Rect getClip(Size a) {
    return Rect.fromLTWH(left, top, width, height);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Rect> old) => true;
}
```